# Help Overriding CartController

Tags: checkout, controllers

I've been pulling my hair out with this... I've looked at probably 20 different tutorials and StackOverflow posts and I can NOT see what is wrong with my code.

I'm trying to override CartController.php

Here is my config file:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <OneGiant_CartRedirect>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </OneGiant_CartRedirect>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <OneGiant_CartRedirect before="Mage_Checkout">OneGiant_Checkout</OneGiant_CartRedirect>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Here is my CartController.php

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class OneGiant_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    protected function _goBack()
    {
        throw new Mage_Exception('Its working!!!!');
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is my OneGiant_CartRedirect.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <OneGiant_CartRedirect>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </OneGiant_CartRedirect>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Here are the file locations:

```
app/code/local/OneGiant/CartRedirect/etc/config.xml
app/code/local/OneGiant/CartRedirect/controllers/CartController.php
app/etc/modules/OneGiant_CartRedirect.xml
```

Please any help would be great.  None of the log files are showing any related errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your config.xml file from this

```
 <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <OneGiant_CartRedirect before="Mage_Checkout">OneGiant_Checkout</OneGiant_CartRedirect>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
```

to

```
 <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <OneGiant_CartRedirect before="Mage_Checkout">OneGiant_CartRedirect</OneGiant_CartRedirect>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
```

And finally change the name of the controller from

```
class OneGiant_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
```

to

```
class OneGiant_CartRedirect_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
```

Your file locations are fine

Comment: This was it!  Thanks so much.  So why is that naming convention important?  Is that the file location?

Answer (score 5):

There are myriad things that could be preventing your override.  The quickest way to get to the bottom of this is some debugging code in the `_validateControllerClassName` method.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
protected function _validateControllerClassName($realModule, $controller)
{
    $controllerFileName = $this->getControllerFileName($realModule, $controller);
    var_dump($realModule, $controller);
    var_dump($controllerFileName);
    if (!$this->validateControllerFileName($controllerFileName)) {
        var_dump(__FILE__ . __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    $controllerClassName = $this->getControllerClassName($realModule, $controller);
    var_dump($controllerClassName);
    if (!$controllerClassName) {
        var_dump(__FILE__ . __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    // include controller file if needed
    if (!$this->_includeControllerClass($controllerFileName, $controllerClassName)) {
        var_dump(__FILE__ . __LINE__);
        return false;
    }

    return $controllerClassName;
}
```

With the above `var_dump`s in place, you should be able to tell which check your controller failed, which will point to your error.

If your controller doesn't show up in the `var_dump`s, it means Magento isn't loading your module configuration, which should open up a new path of debugging.

Also -- don't forget to enabled "developer mode" and set the `display_errors` ini setting to true in `index.php`.

Good luck!